# Adding field to class causes "<constructor> does not define an index 2" exception

Tags: java, tomcat, byte-buddy

I am trying to add a field to sub classes of type java.sql.Connection in an effort to monitor connections that are open for an extended period of time (e.g. connection leak).

This is what I am trying to run with:

```
public class TransactionMonitorVisitor {

    interface FieldSetter {
        void setField(String value);
    }

    interface FieldGetter {
        String getValue();
    }

    public static class ConnectionConstructorVisitor {
        @Advice.OnMethodExit
        public static void intercept(@Advice.Origin Constructor<?> constructor,
                                     @Advice.This Object obj,
                                     @FieldProxy("__txUuid__") FieldSetter accessor
        ) {
            String txUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            System.out.println("Visiting constructor: txUuid=" + txUuid + ", obj=" + obj);
            accessor.setField(txUuid);
        }
    }

    public static class ConnectionMethodVisitor {
        @Advice.OnMethodExit
        public static void intercept(@Advice.Origin Method method,
                                     @FieldProxy("__txUuid__") FieldGetter accessor
        ) {
            String methodName = method.getName();
            String txUuid = accessor.getValue();

            System.out.println("Visiting method: txUuid=" + txUuid + ", method=" + methodName);
        }
    }

    public static void installOn(Instrumentation instrumentation) throws Exception {
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(ElementMatchers.isSubTypeOf(Connection.class))
                .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, javaModule) ->
                        builder.defineField("__txUuid__", String.class)
                            .visit(Advice.to(ConnectionConstructorVisitor.class).on((ElementMatchers.isConstructor())))
                            .visit(Advice.to(ConnectionMethodVisitor.class).on(ElementMatchers.nameMatches("commit|rollback|close")))
                )
                .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
                .installOn(instrumentation);

        System.out.println("Installed :: " + TransactionMonitorVisitor.class.getName());
    }
}
```

When I start up my application (web app in Tomcat) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties) throws java.sql.SQLException does not define an index 2
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$OffsetMapping$ForArgument$Unresolved.resolve(Advice.java:1551)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$OffsetMapping$ForArgument.resolve(Advice.java:1462)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$OffsetMapping$ForArgument$Unresolved.resolve(Advice.java:1564)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$Dispatcher$Inlining$Resolved$ForMethodExit.apply(Advice.java:5818)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$Dispatcher$Inlining$Resolved$AdviceMethodInliner.visitMethod(Advice.java:5414)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$Dispatcher$Inlining$Resolved$AdviceMethodInliner.doApply(Advice.java:5408)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$Dispatcher$Inlining$Resolved$ForMethodExit$AdviceMethodInliner.apply(Advice.java:5902)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$AdviceVisitor$WithExitAdvice.onUserEnd(Advice.java:7503)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$AdviceVisitor.visitMaxs(Advice.java:7251)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining.create(TypeWriter.java:2941)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1633)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RebaseDynamicTypeBuilder.make(RebaseDynamicTypeBuilder.java:200)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$Transformation$Simple$Resolution.apply(AgentBuilder.java:8902)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.doTransform(AgentBuilder.java:9303)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.transform(AgentBuilder.java:9266)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.access$1300(AgentBuilder.java:9044)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$LegacyVmDispatcher.run(AgentBuilder.java:9622)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$LegacyVmDispatcher.run(AgentBuilder.java:9572)
    at ...
```

Based on some research, I've tried adding `.with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)` but that gets me the same error as above.

I saw another place that was using `.disableClassFormatChanges()` in conjunction with `RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION`, but that still doesn't get me error free. The new error is this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot define field for frozen type: class net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType$Frozen.withField(InstrumentedType.java:1149)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Adapter$FieldDefinitionAdapter.materialize(DynamicType.java:3159)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.visit(DynamicType.java:2571)
    at com.calabrio.athena.tx.TransactionMonitorVisitor.lambda$installOn$0(TransactionMonitorVisitor.java:70)
    at com.calabrio.athena.tx.TransactionMonitorVisitor$$Lambda$1/1528637575.transform(Unknown Source)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Transformer$Compound.transform(AgentBuilder.java:2335)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$Transformation$Simple$Resolution.apply(AgentBuilder.java:8899)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.doTransform(AgentBuilder.java:9303)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.transform(AgentBuilder.java:9266)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.access$1300(AgentBuilder.java:9044)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$LegacyVmDispatcher.run(AgentBuilder.java:9622)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$LegacyVmDispatcher.run(AgentBuilder.java:9572)
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, what is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The field proxy can only be used with a MethodDelegation, not with Advice. For Advice, you can bind a custom annotation to a field description. Use Advice.withCustomBindings to do so.

To express a field that is defined at runtime, create a fielddescription.latent.